# Plugin not propagating on field change

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have three entities, let's call them *Alpha*, *Beta* and *Gamma*. There are two plugins registered to trigger on the message *Update*, both post operation and synchronized.

One of them is invoked when the field *aja* in *Alpha* changes and it sets a value of the field *baja* in any related instance of *Beta*. The second is invoked when the field *baja* in *Beta* changes and it sets a value of the field *gaja* in any related *Gamma*.

When I make changes to *aja*, I can confirm that the update is propagated into all *baja*s that are in related instances. Corresponding operation on *baja* updates all related instance's *gaja*.

What drives me nuts is that a change in *aja* (which obviously triggers the first plugin causing an update in *baja*) doesn't trigger the second plugin to set a value in *gaja*.

I expect a change in *Alpha* to propagate down to *Gamma*, because that's how it's supposed to work. I suspect that I'm missing something but after a few attempts, log-checking, crying and swearing, I'm lost. What stupid thing can I be missing?!

Comment: maybe you have a context.Depth check inside your second plugin?

Comment: I do. But the entity isn't calling itself. It's called from another entity, so the depth should be still 1. Right?

Comment: Oh, dude... I just printed out the depth explicitly and guess what. You were spot on right. Apparently the depth accumulates between entities as well. That raises the question how to handle if I need to limit depth on self-recurrent entities to a certain maximum and an other value when it's invoked from elsewhere... Post your stuff as a reply, anyway, so I can mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you are facing normally is connected to a `IExecutionContext.Depth` check

[https://msdn.microsoft.com/en
us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.iexecutioncontext.depth.aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.iexecutioncontext.depth.aspx)

Because the plugins are synchronous they run in the current transaction, they cause an increment of the `Depth` property.

Probably a check like `if (context.Depth > 2) { return; }` inside your second plugin will solve the problem.